# Distributed Java Application with RestFul

Tags: java, restful-architecture, distributed-system

I'm trying to create a Java Distributed Application, where i have two parts:

1) A Java EE running over Tomcat WebServer that have all business rules, JPA beans and crud operations. This part of architecture also have a RestFul layer that delegate all operations to a Service Layer, where all business lives.

2) A Java SE (Swing) that don't have any business logic and don't know JPA or any orm framework, a thin client. This just have Swing Forms and DTO (Data Transfer Object) Java Class. When this part need any database operation, it call Java EE RestFul (First part), passing DTO as JSON and this DTO is converted in Java Bean (JPA) in WebServer.

This is just a ideia of project but i have some doubts:
1) my biggest problem is convert DTO  to Java Bean. I think this will be a trouble, because i need re-find the Bean in JPA (to attatch it in JPA PersistenceContext) and set property by property from DTO to JPA. There is any easy way to do it ? OBS: my dto is equal Java Bean but don't have JPA annotations. Is like a Class clone.

2) JSON is more faster way to Transfer data between RestFul?

3) can i control sessionScoped from Swing to Java EE ?

Comment: I think using a DTO is a good idea. You can try http://dozer.sourceforge.net/ or BeanUtils to copy values from and To to Entities.

Comment: But imagine this situation: i can retrieve a Java Bean with some property not initialized, so in Dto this property will be null. In back (Dto to Java Bean) , JPA can understand to set null in database.

Comment: With Dozer you can configure these mappings can be configured also can raise issues or add default values.  If you are expecting Not NULL values then you must validate the data received from server side in your rest client.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will wait if someone have more options about this architecture